# config file error: expected 'url' for dictionary value @ data['remote']['origin']

Tags: git, dvc, dagshub

I have installed git and DVC and I push my git to dagshub without any error, but I faced with error with dvc push.

I run this command `dvc push --all-commits` and I faced with this error:

> ERROR: failed to push data to the cloud - config file error: expected
> 'url' for dictionary value @ data['remote']['origin']

I'll be thankful for your help.

Comment: Please create an issue in https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues (don't forget to attach `dvc doctor` and log for `dvc push --all-commits -v`).